# How to synchronize some part of my method in asp.net webservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, synchronization

I want to synchronize some part of method. I've tried with lock(this) but when I observed the logs two requests are processing at a time so it was unable to handle so I want to handle only  one request at a time.

Please help me how to implement this.

I've tried the following code.

```
  lock (this)
   {

  obj.ConvertFile(inputFilename, outputFullPath, null, batchProcess,   null);

   }
```

But it wasn't worked for me.
So I've created static variable with in the lock()

```
  lock (this)
   {
    i++;               
  obj.ConvertFile(inputFilename, outputFullPath, null, batchProcess,   null);

   }
```

This one also not worked for me.

Please help me how to implement synchronization that only one request will be handled at a time when more than 2 requests received.

Comment: Please show the declaration of your variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to lock in ASP.NET web service (which runs multiple threads inside one process), you should not synchronise on `this` (though I'm only guessing what `this` class is).

You can use the following object as your lock object. It is static so it will be shared across all instances of your class.

```
private static Object thisLock = new Object();
```

and lock using that

```
lock(thisLock) 
{
}
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> In general, avoid locking on a public type, or instances beyond your code's control. The common constructs lock (this), lock (typeof (MyType)), and lock ("myLock") violate this guideline:
>
> - lock (this) is a problem if the instance can be accessed publicly.
> - lock (typeof (MyType)) is a problem if MyType is publicly accessible.
> - lock("myLock") is a problem because any other code in the process using the same string, will share the same lock.
>
> Best practice is to define a private object to lock on, or a private static object variable to protect data common to all instances.